# Problem with AutoFilter when selectiong from a Drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

[image: In the image you can see the columns where i need the filter to get activated, and its working prperly until i select "Example"]Sorry for that

I have 2 dropdown lists one for the lenguage and one for the possition
verything is working well but i added a new possition in this case "EXAMPLE" and thats when it stops working
There is a match between the name of the columns and the constants that i have declared
FEV Mitarbeiter / Employee
externer Mitarbeiter / external Employee
TME Mitarbeiter / Employee
Student / Student
Example /Example

The error that i have says "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"
I did some research and it says that is because of the cells have the filter activated but im not sure

Here is the code

### Function

Option Explicit

```
Sub set_language_and_view(sLanguage As String, sEmployeeCategory As String)
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Cells(ROW_LIST_CHECK, COL_LIST_CHECK) = s_CHECK Then
        'Identified List-Sheet
        With Sheets(i)
            '============= SET LANGUAGE
            If sLanguage = sGERMAN Then
                'Show German
                .Columns(COL_LIST_CATEGORY_DE).Hidden = False
                .Columns(COL_LIST_TASK_DE).Hidden = False
                .Columns(COL_LIST_LINK_DE).Hidden = False
                'Hide English
                .Columns(COL_LIST_CATEGORY_ENG).Hidden = True
                .Columns(COL_LIST_TASK_ENG).Hidden = True
                .Columns(COL_LIST_LINK_ENG).Hidden = True
            Else
                'Show English
                .Columns(COL_LIST_CATEGORY_ENG).Hidden = False
                .Columns(COL_LIST_TASK_ENG).Hidden = False
                .Columns(COL_LIST_LINK_ENG).Hidden = False
                'Hide German
                .Columns(COL_LIST_CATEGORY_DE).Hidden = True
                .Columns(COL_LIST_TASK_DE).Hidden = True
                .Columns(COL_LIST_LINK_DE).Hidden = True
            End If
            
            '============ SET EMPLOYEE CATEGORY
            Dim d As Variant
            Dim col As Integer

            Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With d
                .Add sFEVEMPLOYEE, COL_LIST_FEV_EMPLOYEE
                .Add sEXTERNALEMPLOYEE, COL_LIST_EXTERNAL_EMPLOYEE
                .Add sTMEEMPLOYEE, COL_LIST_TME_EMPLOYEE
                '.Add sEXAMPLE, COL_LIST_EXAMPLE
                .Add sSTUDENTWORKER, COL_LIST_STUDENT_WORKER
                
                
            End With
            
            .Activate
        
            col = d.Item(sEmployeeCategory)
               If .FilterMode = True Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            .Range(Cells(ROW_LIST_FILTER, COL_LIST_FIRST), Cells(ROW_LIST_FILTER, COL_LIST_LAST)).AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:="<>"
            

        End With
    End If
Next i
Sheets(ws_DETAILS).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Declarations

```
 Option Explicit

 ' ----- DETAILS SHEET
 Public Const ws_DETAILS = "Details"
 Public Const COL_DETAILS_INFO = 3
 Public Const ROW_DETAILS_EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY = 12
 Public Const ROW_DETAILS_LANGUAGE = 13`enter code here`

 ' ----- ALL CHECKLISTS
 Public Const ROW_LIST_FILTER = 4
 Public Const COL_LIST_FIRST = 1

Public Const COL_LIST_CATEGORY_DE = 4
Public Const COL_LIST_CATEGORY_ENG = 5

Public Const COL_LIST_TASK_DE = 6
Public Const COL_LIST_TASK_ENG = 7

Public Const COL_LIST_LINK_DE = 9
Public Const COL_LIST_LINK_ENG = 10

Public Const COL_LIST_FEV_EMPLOYEE = 12
Public Const COL_LIST_EXTERNAL_EMPLOYEE = 13
Public Const COL_LIST_TME_EMPLOYEE = 14
Public Const COL_LIST_STUDENT_WORKER = 15

Public Const COL_LIST_EXAMPLE = 16
Public Const COL_LIST_LAST = COL_LIST_EXAMPLE   

'-------Identified Sheet as List
Public Const COL_LIST_CHECK = 1
Public Const ROW_LIST_CHECK = 4
Public Const s_CHECK = "Status / Status"

 '-------CONSTANTS
 Public Const sGERMAN = "Deutsch"
 Public Const sENGLISH = "English"
 Public Const sFEVEMPLOYEE = "FEV Mitarbeiter / Employee"
 Public Const sEXTERNALEMPLOYEE = "externer Mitarbeiter / external Employee"
 Public Const sTMEEMPLOYEE = "TME Mitarbei`enter code here`ter / Employee"
 Public Const sSTUDENTWORKER = "Student / Student"
 Public Const sEXAMPLE = "Example /Example"
```

---

Call Function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim language As String, employee_category As String


    If Target.Column = COL_DETAILS_INFO And (Target.Row = 
ROW_DETAILS_LANGUAGE Or Target.Row = ROW_DETAILS_EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY) 
Then
    language = Cells(ROW_DETAILS_LANGUAGE, COL_DETAILS_INFO)
    employee_category = Cells(ROW_DETAILS_EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY, 
COL_DETAILS_INFO)
    Call set_language_and_view(language, employee_category)
    
End If

End Sub
```

> Blockquote

Comment: What is `.AddsFEMPLOYEE, COL_LIST_EMPLOYEE`? Is it `.Add FEMPLOYEE, COL_LIST_EMPLOYEE`? What are the values of the constants? Is this thing part of a function, how is it called?

Comment: More strange things: `ActivateSheet`: Do you mean `ActiveSheet`? `.Range` is invalid except used inside a `With`-block. Could you post the real code (at least the relevant part)? Have you checked that all the constants are defined? Do you use `Option Explicit` (why not?). If your code works for some of the cases, check what is special with the case where it fails.

Comment: I hope it helps get things more clear

Comment: Pls. give additional infos on the followings. Sheets(i) cells content in the Range("A4:P4") or if you can a snapshot of the Sheets(i) Range("A1:P16") with dummy but similar contents if contains sensitive data. I can sometimes detect the error, but need this info to clarify the reason.

Comment: Is it okay with that?

Comment: Thank you for the try but it did not work

Comment: This is the error, if you apply the AutoFilter method on a Range when there is an active autofilter is on the sheet. Stop before the line which cause the error and check the sheet of it.